# ArgumentError at / wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tried looking at previous Rails wrong arguments questions but no luck. Below is full error trace in console, followed by main relevant files in the Rails 4 project. The problem is in the controller but I don't know why it's failing.

```
Started GET "/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&confirm_number=NTSOTHJN&email=otherjamesgray%40gmail.com" for ::1 at 2015-06-11 10:51:28 +0100
Processing by SearchReservationsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "confirm_number"=>"NTSOTHJN", "email"=>"otherjamesgray@gmail.com"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (0 for 2):
  app/controllers/search_reservations_controller.rb:4:in `index'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  /Users/dan14/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/dan14/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/dan14/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Controller:

```
class SearchReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def index    
    if params[:confirm_number] && params[:email]   
      @search_reservation = SearchReservation.new
    end
  end

  def search_reservation_params
    params.require(:search_reservation).permit(:confirm_number, :email, :size, :first_name, :last_name, :session_id)  
  end

end
```

View:

```
<h1>Search for your reservation</h1>

<p>
  <%= form_tag(root_url, :method => :get ) %>
  <%= label_tag 'Confirmation Number:' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :confirm_number %>

  <%= label_tag 'Email:' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email %>

  <%= submit_tag "Lookup", name: nil %>
</p>

<% if @search_reservation %>
  <dl id ="reservation_info">
   <dt>Number of people / size of booking:</dt>
    <dd><%= @search_reservation.size %></dd>
    <dt>First Name:</dt>
    <dd><%= @search_reservation.first_name %></dd>
    <dt>Last Name:</dt>
    <dd><%= @search_reservation.last_name %></dd>
    <dt>Meal session:</dt>
    <dd><%= @search_reservation.session_id %></dd>
  </dl>
<% end %>
```

Model:

```
class SearchReservation
  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name, :size, :session_id

  def initialize(confirm_number, email)
    client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://placeholder-wsdl-url-link", follow_redirects: :follow_redirects)
      response = client.call(:search_for_reservation, message: { 'ConfirmationNumber' => confirm_number, 'EMail' => email })    
      if response.success?
        data = response.to_array(:search_for_reservation_response, :reservation).first
        if data
          @first_name = data[:first_name]
          @last_name = data[:last_name]
          @size = data[:size]
          @session_id = data[:session_id]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix :

```
def index    
  if params[:confirm_number] && params[:email]   
    @search_reservation = SearchReservation.new params[:confirm_number], params[:email]
  end
end
```

You forgot to pass the arguments to the `initializer` method of the `SearchReservation` class. That's causing the error.